# How can i set the elementScrollBehavior capability using the nodejs selenium webdriver

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I create the driver as follows:

```
driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).build();
```

How can I set the `elementScrollBehavior` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the firefoxprofile [setPreference](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html#setPreference(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) Method

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
DesiredCapabilities dc=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
// this sets general.autoScroll to false and you can get all the keys you need from about:config to set your preferences
profile.setPreference("general.autoScroll", false);
dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
Webdriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your example is a nodejs example and not rather a Java example?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the Node.js equivalent of Jyothishwar's code (assuming `firefox` has been `require`d):

```
var profile = new firefox.Profile();
profile.setPreference('general.autoScroll', false);

var opts = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile);

driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox())
                                .setFirefoxOptions(opts)
                                .build();
```